# Penney's Game probabilities

Tags: python

I want to repeat a list ("llista") several times to see how many times does one outcome win (XXX) or the other one (CCC) to calculate their probabilities. This list has to generate randomly again every time I want to know who won the game. I would be grateful if someone helped me finish my college homework.

```
CCC=0
XXX=0
llista=[]
i=0
llançaments=100
a=1

while i < llançaments:
    llista.append(np.random.randint(0,2))
    i+=1

for i in range (len(llista)):
    if i+2 >= len(llista):
        break
    if llista[i] == 0 and llista[i+1] == 0 and llista[i-1] == 0:
        CCC+=1
        break
    if llista[i] == 1 and llista[i+1] == 1 and llista[i-1] == 1:
        XXX+=1
        break

print(CCC)
print(XXX)
```

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I would go about it.

```
import random

CCC=0
XXX=0

for count in range (100) :
    llista = [random.randint (0, 2) for x in range (3)]
    if llista == [0, 0, 0] :
        CCC += 1
    if llista == [1, 1, 1]:
        XXX += 1

print (f'CCC equals {CCC}.')
print (f'XXX equals {XXX}.')
```